# Parent's display set to none, but child still visible?

Tags: html, css

I'm really confused over this one, I've set the parent `.container` display to none but `#bottom-bar` is still visible. I don't understand? I want to make the whole of `.container` visible once I've sorted the canvas but the child is visible before that, which ruins it all?

```css
canvas {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container canvas,
#bottom-bar {
  position: absolute;
}

#bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  <div id="bottom-bar">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Simon please be more careful when editing posts; you removed code from the post.

Comment: \o/ | I'm so *so* sorry, I didn't have a clue I had done it. I will take  more attention next time. @TylerH  Thank you very much for telling me.

Answer (score 2):

There's a stray red dot in your CSS that will be visible if you paste the code into an editor.

```css
canvas {
  background: black;
}

/*  
​ <-- REMOVE THIS 
.container {
  display: none;
}*/


.container {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container canvas,
#bottom-bar {
  position: absolute;
}

#bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  <div id="bottom-bar">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jonny is wrong here. sol's answer is correct.